# Hibernate, Spring and two databases

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, configuration

I have a problem is with class of configuration for hibernate, where I am trying to createing connector for two databases mysql. For instance if I created one instance data source -all was good, but after append another I get report:

> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of method sessionFactory in
>   pl.lasota.databaseaccess.ConfigBeanForDatabase required a single bean,
>   but 2 were found:
>     - dataSource: defined by method 'dataSource' in class path resource [pl/lasota/databaseaccess/ConfigBeanForDatabase.class]
>     - dataSourceUser: defined by method 'dataSourceUser' in class path resource [pl/lasota/databaseaccess/ConfigBeanForDatabase.class]
>
> Action:
>
> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer
>   to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean
>   that should be consumed

Beans are marked annotations Qualification. I don't understand why this do not work properly.

This is my class with configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigBeanForDatabase {

 @Bean(name = "dataSource")
 public DataSource dataSource() {
  BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
  dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql1");
  dataSource.setUsername("****");
  dataSource.setPassword("****");
  return dataSource;
 }

 @Autowired
 @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
 public SessionFactory sessionFactory(
  @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
  LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
  sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
  sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(Comment.class);
  return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
 }

 @Autowired
 @Bean
 public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
  @Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
  HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(
   sessionFactory);
  return transactionManager;
 }
 @Autowired
 @Bean
 public MysqlPlaceDaoImpl mysqlPlaceDaoImpl(@Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
  return new MysqlPlaceDaoImpl(sessionFactory);
 }

 @Autowired
 @Bean
 public MysqlSiteDaoImpl mysqlSiteDaoImpl(@Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
  return new MysqlSiteDaoImpl(sessionFactory);
 }





 @Bean(name = "dataSourceUser")
 public DataSource dataSourceUser() {
  BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
  dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql2");
  dataSource.setUsername("****");
  dataSource.setPassword("****");
  return dataSource;
 }

 @Autowired
 @Bean(name = "sessionFactoryUser")
 public SessionFactory sessionFactoryUser(@Qualifier("dataSourceUser") DataSource dataSource) {
  LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
  sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
  sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
  return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
 }

 @Autowired
 @Bean
 public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManagerUser(
  @Qualifier("sessionFactoryUser") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
  HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(
   sessionFactory);
  return transactionManager;
 }


 @Autowired
 @Bean
 public MysqlUserDaoImpl mysqlUserDaoImpl(@Qualifier("sessionFactoryUser") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
  return new MysqlUserDaoImpl(sessionFactory);
 }


 private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
  properties.put(" hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path", "ehcache.xml");
  properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
  properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
  properties.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", true);
  properties.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
  properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", true);
  properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
  return properties;
 }
}
```

I tried add annotation @primary, also divide class with configuration on two class. Sorry for my english.

Comment: What is the other datasource?

Comment: this mean that: mysql->base1->table1;table2  other mysql->base2->table3;table4

Comment: Adding @Primary over first dataSource() worked for me. Can you retry?

Comment: <code>Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager,transactionManagerUser</code>   I should add @Primary to all bean ?

Comment: But if I will add '@Primary' I will blocking to add another configuration to other database. I added  '@Primary' to transactionManager but now Hibernate dont know what is User persister.